# ¿Cómo comparar dos jTable y los datos que NO se encuentren en la comparación ponerlos en otro jTable?

Tags: java

El código está en JAVA

Tengo dos jTable con información de unas personas, una tiene toda la información como: tipo de documento, numero de documento, entre otros datos, la otra solamente tiene el numero de documento el cual es traído desde una base de datos. Debo comparar ambos jTable con numero de documento y los datos que NO estén ponerlos en otro jTable para ser exportado en Excel.

el método para encontrar los que si coinciden ya lo tengo:

Gracias por la ayuda!

```
public void encontrarexis() {
        int c = 0;
        DefaultTableModel tablase = (DefaultTableModel) this.jTable3.getModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
            String al = this.jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
            //System.out.println("AL "+al);
            for (int j = 0; j < jTable2.getRowCount(); j++) {
                String validar = this.jTable2.getValueAt(j, 0).toString();
                // System.out.println("Validar "+validar);
                if (al.equals(validar)) {
                    c++;
                    String p;
                    p = al;
                    System.out.println("igual                                           " + c + " For al: " + i + " For validar: " + j);
                    System.out.println(p + " : " + validar);
                    tablase.addRow(new Object[]{p});
                    break;

                }

            }

            this.jTable3.setModel(tablase);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creo que sería conveniente que mostraras tu código. no puede responderse sobre un par de consultas sin ver esas consultas. Además así mostrarás que ya estás trabajando sobre el tema y haciendo pruebas. En la comunidad no es bien recibido el tipo de preguntas: necesito hacer ésto con los siguientes requisitos y esperar que otros hagan el trabajo por ti. Un saludo

Comment: Añadido, gracias por el dato (soy nuevo)